# My spring boot application when it's api is called after start up first time it takes more time to give response

Tags: performance, startup

My spring boot application when it's api is called after start up first time it takes more time to give response, however after few multiple subsequent requests the response time reduced to very small number.How I can make sure that all requests irrespective of first or second return response in short time??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Spring Rest services slow on the first request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019528/why-are-spring-rest-services-slow-on-the-first-request)