# how to find out which function(s) took most time during API invocation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, profiling, visualvm

i am trying to debug why my spring boot application takes around 200-ms to respond to an API, and for subsequent hits of same API it takes around 10-ms.
`no caching is involved in API.`
I am using `VisualVM` and seems there is a CPU spike only for first time and no spike is observed for subsequent hits.

**How can i get to know which functions took most time/intensive when i made the first API call.**

Update: [Why are Spring Rest services slow on the first request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019528/why-are-spring-rest-services-slow-on-the-first-request)

[image: CPU Usage]

Answer (score 1):

You can use build profiler in Intellij Idea and check the `Flame Graph` .

`Flame Graph` – a convenient way to visually assess the performance of various code paths and their share in overall CPU/memory usage

[image]

I'm not going to copy the whole docs, but check the Intellij Idea docs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/read-the-profiling-report.html

Answer (score 0):

what about [Glowroot](https://glowroot.org/) it's a very useful and good Java Agent, that will help you to find your problem